# Neural Network test set performance low

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I have implemented a neural network in Matlab R2013a for character recognition. I have used trainbr function for nn training. 80% samples were used for training and the rest for testing. When i plot the confusion matrix, i get 100% accuracy on the training set. But for the test set the accuracy is very low(around 60%). What could be possibly wrong?

Comment: It sounds like you could be overfitting to your training data if you get 100% training accuracy. Have you tried using a cross-validation scheme, or possibly just reducing the size of your training set?

Comment: Can you please explain how to use the cross validation scheme since i cant reduce the training data?

Comment: I recommend starting with the Wikipedia page on k-fold cross-validation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)#K-fold_cross-validation. MATLAB has the function `cvpartition` which can help you split your training set up into folds: http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/cvpartition.html